# Is there any way to use latest css properties to other browser that not supported to that browser

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I want to use those properties that are not supported to internet explorer 11, how can I use it in any way like a javascript library or anything else for this issue

Comment: It depends on what css properties you want to use. `autoprefixer` might be a good candidate, but it won't cover everything.

Comment: I want to use object-fit, fit-content, min-content, max-content but in these properties, no prefix works

Comment: There's no easy fix like prefix or polyfill for all these properties in IE. The workaround in IE is depending on the situation how you use them. We can use other css styles to achieve the same result in IE. The situations are different in different cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to to some research and google for *[polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/polyfill)* or *[shims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shim)* for each property not supported by your targeted browsers.

There are lists on the internet for common solutions ([Example on GitHub](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills)).

Here, as an example, a polyfill for `object-fit` for older IE-versions:
https://github.com/fregante/object-fit-images

It is not good practice to offer links on StackOverflow - as links do outdate quickly - but I wanted to provide examples for what to search for.

Comment: Better yet: Provide modern solutions and find a working compromise for older browsers. It does not have to be bells and whistles for those. A clean,simple, readable fallback-solution is often a better choice.

Comment: Always provide a helpful comment with a downvote, to explain why an answer is not useful. It helps increasing the quality of this community for all of us.